# Is mounting an ext4fs (any fs for that matter) on subdirectory of a linux FUSE file system allowed?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse

I have a FUSE mount point at `/home/abc/fuse/` and it has few a directories and files inside. `/home/abc/fuse/foo.txt`, `/home/abc/fuse/bar.out`, `/home/abc/fuse/logs/` etc. Now I want to mount an ext4 fs on `/home/abc/fuse/ext4fs/`.

Is this allowed? If so, then what happens to the requests to `/home/abc/fuse/ext4fs/*` ? Will they arrive at FUSE callbacks too or just the ext4fs ?

Forgive me if this has already been answered elsewhere. I tried with my best searching skills. Please add a link to the answer if it exists.